# Find number of possibilities for equal distribution

Tags: algorithm

Suppose we have 8 candy bags. Each bag contains candies `1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8`.

The candies have to be distributed between two persons such that each person receives the same number of candies. The number of candy bags each person receives  does not matter.

For example, `{1,2,3,4,8}` and `{5,6,7}` is one possibility. Another possibility is `{3,4,5,6}` and `{1,2,7,8}`.

One has to calculate the total number of possibilities.

I can think about a brute force algorithm to calculate the sum and check for equality. But the solution does not look good to me.

How can I approach this question ?

Comment: Total number of candies a person receives. sum of  {1,2,3,4,8} is 18 and  {5,6,7} is 18. Similarly {3,4,5,6}  and {1,2,7,8} sum to 18 each. I hope your doubt is clear.

Comment: The fact that the number of bags is fixed at 8 means that brute-force enumeration of all 256 possibilities is actually no problem at all.  It would be interesting to consider the generalised version of the problem where we have some (multiple of 4) number of numbers.

Answer (score 1):

This is a well known problem: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_problem

Comment: This is a *very special case of* that well known problem.  Maybe there's some additional structure to exploit?  (I can't see any yet though.)

Answer (score 1):

You can reduce the number of possibilities you need to check for by noticing that there are a total of 36 candies, so each person needs to receive exactly 18 candies. You can reduce it further by noticing that the most number of bags either person can have is 5, since there is no combination of 6 bags or greater whose sum is <= 18 candies, and likewise the fewest number of bags either person can have is 3.

A brute force method would not take long to calculate. Here I use a series of 5 nested loops:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main ()
{
    int num_possibilities = 0;
    int sum;
    int a, b, c, d, e;
    for (a = 1; a <= 8; a++) {
        for (b = a + 1; b <= 8; b++) {
            for (c = b + 1; c <= 8; c++) {
                sum = a + b + c;
                if (sum == 18) {
                    num_possibilities++;
                    printf ("%d %d %d\n", a, b, c);
                    continue;
                }
                for (d = c + 1; d <= 8; d++) {
                    sum = a + b + c + d;
                    if (sum == 18) {
                        num_possibilities++;
                        printf ("%d %d %d %d\n", a, b, c, d);
                        continue;
                    }
                    for (e = d + 1; e <= 8; e++) {
                        sum = a + b + c + d + e;
                        if (sum == 18) {
                            num_possibilities++;
                            printf ("%d %d %d %d %d\n", a, b, c, d, e);
                            continue;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    printf ("Number of possibilities = %d", num_possibilities);
}
```

Loop variable `a` represents the number of candies in the first bag Person 1 selected out of the 8 bags. Loop variable `b` represents the number of candies in the second bag Person 1 selected, and so on.

Since we only need to count the total number of candies Person 1 has in all his bags, we can ignore Person 2 completely in the algorithm.

The above code produces an answer of 14 different combinations (I hope it's right!).

Comment: A further reduction by a factor 2 is possible by noting that the solutions come in pairs: e.g. {1,2,3,4,8} and {5,6,7} is paired with {5,6,7} and {1,2,3,4,8}; only one needs to be enumerated, we can then multiply the found number by 2.

Comment: To make @Henry's suggestion "actionable", all we need to do is decide at the outset that person 1 will take some particular bag, e.g. bag #8.  This works, since *one* of the two people must take bag #8.  It also means that we now only have to find combinations of 2-4 other bags that sum to exactly 10 (this is why bag #8 is a better choice than bag #1).

Comment: Good point, @Henry. My algorithm assumes that Person 1 having {1 2 3 4 8} and Person 2 {5 6 7} is a different case than Person 1 {5 6 7} and Person 2 {1 2 3 4 8}. The OP didn't specify whether these should be considered the same or different cases. Either way, the number of iterations could be reduced by a factor of 2, as you say.